# Integration by substitution simplifying

Tags: calculus

I wanna integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{e^x-e^{-2x}+2}$but after substituting $e^x=t$ and simplifying I get trouble trying to use partial fraction expansion on the expression
$\frac{t}{(t+1)(t^2+t-1)}$. I know that $t^2+t-1=(t+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})(t+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$ but this is troublesome to work with (not allowed to use calculators etc). Any suggestions to facilitate the calculations?

Comment: It might be useful to note that $\frac{1+\sqrt5}2=\phi$ and that $\frac{1-\sqrt5}2=1-\phi$. This can simplify the calculations — just remember the identity $\phi^2=\phi+1$.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in having $\sqrt 5$ in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to factor the quadratic. Use the usual partial fractions technique:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{t}{6^3+2t^2-1}&=\frac{A}{t+1}+\frac{Bt+C}{t^2+t-1}\\\\
&=\frac{(A+B)t^2+(A+B+C)t+(C-A)}{(t+1)(t^2+t-1)}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so $A+B=0=C-A$, and $A+B+C=1$. This is an easy system to solve: $C=A$, $B=-A$, and hence $A=1$, so we have

$$\int_1^e\left(\frac1{t+1}-\frac{t-1}{t^2+t-1}\right)dt\;,$$

assuming no silly errors on my part. The first term is easy; for the second, note that

$$\frac{t-1}{t^2+t-1}=\frac{(t+1)-2}{t^2+t-1}=\frac{t+1}{t^2+t-1}-\frac2{\left(t+\frac12\right)^2-\frac54}\;.$$

Comment: you still need to factor $(t+1/2)^2 - 5/4$ as op had already done.

Comment: @abel: No, you don’t: you can use a trig substitution.

Comment: what is the trig substitution to integrate $\frac{1}{(t+1/2)^2 - 5/4}?$ and why?

Comment: @abel: It's a $\frac1{u^2-a^2}$ form, for which $u=a\sec\theta$ is a bog-standard approach. Or you can change the sign of the term and make it $\frac1{a^2-u^2}$, for which $u=a\sin\theta$ is a standard approach.

Comment: that $\int \frac{2}{(t+1/2)^2 - 5/4}\, dt = \ln(\frac{t+1/2 +\sqrt 5/2}{t+1/2-\sqrt 5/2})$ there is no way out.

Comment: @abel: I know what the result is. I also know at least three different mathematically legitimate ways to reach it. Apparently you know only one and haven't even bothered to try the two perfectly straightforward trig substitutions, both of which are standard fare in any decent basic calculus course.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you show how to continue using one of those substitutions? With $u=asin\theta$ I get $du = d\theta a\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{a^2}}$ and 
$\frac{1}{a^2(1-sin^2\theta} d\theta a\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{a^2}}$ which can be simplified to 
$\frac{d\theta \sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{a^2}}}{cos^2\theta}$. 
Is this correct so far?

Comment: @Rousseau: If $u=a\sin\theta$, then $du=a\cos\theta\,d\theta$, so $$\int\frac{du}{a^2-u^2}= \frac1a\int\frac{\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}= \frac1a\int\sec\theta\,d\theta= \frac1a\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C\;.$$ To get back to $u$, note that $\tan\theta=\frac{u}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}$ and $\sec\theta=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}$; you end up with $\frac1{2a}\ln\left|\frac{a+u}{a-u}\right|+C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\frac{t}{(t + 1)(t^2 + t - 1)} = \frac{1}{t + 1} - \frac{t - 1}{t^2 + t - 1} = \frac{1}{t + 1} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{2t + 1}{t^2 + t - 1} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{t^2 + t - 1},$$

you may integrate each term on the right separately. The first one will give you $\log|t + 1| + C$. The second one will also give you a log: use the $u$-substitution $u = t^2 + t - 1$ and note that $du = (2t + 1)\, dt$. Even the last one will give you a log. Write $t^2 + t - 1 = (t + 1/4)^2 - 5/4$ and note that by partial fraction decomposition,

$$\int \frac{dv}{v^2 - a^2} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left|\frac{v - a}{v + a}\right| + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) $\frac{t}{(t + 1)(t^2 + t + 1)} = \frac1{1 + t} + \frac1{t^2 + t + 1} - \frac{t}{t^2 + t + 1}$.

2) $t^2 + t + 1 = (t + 1/2)^2 + \frac34$.